# How i can sort string in c#?

Tags: c#, android, json

I'm developing an Android application with Visual Studio / Xamarin I have to sort a string that contains a `JSON` object that is like this:

```
[{"Entities":{"en-US":{"Items":[{"Resources":[], "Id":"1234567","Name":"Filter","ContentBody":"","Cover":"","Language":,"Action":0}],"Id":"1234567","Name":"04 SOMETHING","ContentBody":"","Cover":"","Language":"en-US","Action":0},"it-IT":{"Items":[{"Resources":[], "Id":"1234567","Name":"Filtro","ContentBody":"","Cover":"","Language":null,"Action":0}]
```

This is a small part of my json, I need to sort JSON by name ("04 SOMETHING") this "name" is composed by a numeric ID and a String (i need to sort by this id).

How i can do this ?

Comment: Mind using [`Json.NET`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)?

Comment: Use Newtonsofts' [`Deserializeobject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm)

Comment: Could someone make me one example please ?

@FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ I edited my code

Comment: @Rakitić, I have read something about Linq, is it a good 
approach?

Comment: @Max you don't need Linq for this. Just try that link I shared. It's very easy to parse a `Json` in C#

Comment: @Rakitić I have deserialize my json:
var rawData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SectionItem>>(json);

Now ?

Comment: how did you generate your classes? if you haven't, you could easily do so by copying the json and going to vs and selecting RightClick -> Paste Special -> As Json classes something like that

Comment: After you do so, add the class code to the question so that we may suggest you a LINQ query for sorting the data, accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code :

```
JArray sorted = new JArray(jsonResult["Items"].OrderBy(obj => obj["Id"]));

jsonResult["Items"] = sorted;
```

Comment: In my case jsonResult is: rawData ?

 var rawData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SectionItem>>(json);